# Inkwell Widget allowing unexpected area clicks

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a button created with the help of the Container and the Inkwell widget. Here is the code:

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            // validating todo item
            if (todoController.text.isNotEmpty) {
              todoProviderObj.addTodo(
                TodoModel(
                  id: UniqueKey().toString(),
                  title: todoController.text,
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
```

Now the problem is that the Inkwell is allowing area clicks where it should not be allowing, as you can see in the below picture (I'm sorry that it is not showing my cursor but my cursor is placed outside the highlighted circle and the clicks are working outside that highlighted area):

[image]

Is there any way I can solve it?

Comment: can you share more code

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please have a look now. I have updated the code.

Comment: i need full widget, because everythinbg is working fine , can test your question and then paste it for me .

Comment: This is the full widget code for the button. Do You want the complete code for the input box and the button?

Comment: yes, i think errors are coming from there. also test before what you paste here,

Comment: TBH, I feel that the issue only exists in this code (the code I have posted). and yes, the pasted code is what I intended to paste.

Comment: sorry but can you edit that image &  draw the cursor point ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have a 60*60 square that transformed into the circle shape but still it's a square, when you click outside of the circle actually you are clicking on this 60*60 area.

I recommed using floating action button or elevatedbutton.

[image]

Comment: Yeah! I'm using GestureDetector instead. But is there any way to fix this or Is this the actual behavior of InkWell?

Comment: Maybe by removing the height, width and using the padding it gonna works.